# Reliable way to get role definition

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

What is the best way to get role definition id of the predefined role (like, reader, admin)?

I'm trying to configure a folder to have members have only read permissions. For this I'm removing existing role assignments to members and adding reader role to them. SharePoint REST API requires me to provide role definition id, but I can't find a way to get it reliably.

It seems like I can get it by name `_api/web/roledefinitions/getbyname('Read')`, but I'm concerned how to handle the case of non-English locale. I would expect it can be searched by type kind `_api/web/roledefinitions/getbytypekind(2)`, but I can't get it working. It gives me an error `Cannot find resource for the request getbytypekind.`

Also, can default role definition be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like I can get it by name
>   _api/web/roledefinitions/getbyname('Read'), but I'm concerned how to handle the case of non-English locale

that's correct, [`SP.RoleDefinition.name` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246160.aspx) could vary per locale, so retrieving role definition by [role type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246683.aspx) is definitely more reliable in this regard, [`SP.RoleDefinitionCollection.getByType` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee658615%28v%3Doffice.14%29) could be utilized here, for example:

```
/_api/web/roledefinitions/getByType(<roletypeid>)
```

where `roletypeid` corresponds to [`SP.RoleType` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee658615%28v%3Doffice.14%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the role definition list by

```
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/RoleDefinitions
```

Then you can get the specific role by id(like read),so we don't need to care the locale issue:

```
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741826)
```

The role list and id:

```
FullControl(Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741829))
Design(Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741828))
Edit(Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741830))
Contribute(Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741827))
Read(Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741826))
Limited Access(Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741825))
System.LimitedView(Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741926))
System.LimitedEdit(Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741927))
Create new subsites(Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741924))
View Only(Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741925))
```

We can use the default role or customize our own role, so i think Microsoft do not need to provide API for deleting built-in roles.

Although we can use the getbytype method too, but the list of role type values are not very user friendly.(see more in the link below)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_RoleDefinitionCollectionGetById
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_RoleDefinitionCollectionGetByType